# env-entry from ejb-jar.xml is null

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jboss-arquillian

I have 100th problem with java EE. I don't understand what the hell is going on

Here is my EJB

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Remote(ItemRemote.class)
public class ItemEJB implements ItemLocal, ItemRemote {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "demo_unit")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Resource(name = "currencyEntry")
    private String currency;

    @Resource(name = "changeRateEntry")
    private Float changeRate;

    @Override
    public List<Book> findBooks() {
        TypedQuery<Book> query = em.createNamedQuery("findAllBooks", Book.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<CD> findCDs() {
        TypedQuery<CD> query = em.createNamedQuery("findAllCDs", CD.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }


    public Book createBook(Book book) {
        em.persist(book);
        return book;
    }


    public CD createCD(CD cd) {
        em.persist(cd);
        return cd;
    }

    public void deleteCD(CD cd) {
        em.remove(em.merge(cd));
    }

    public Item convertPrice(Item item){
        item.setPrice(item.getPrice()*changeRate);
        item.setCurrency(currency);
        return item;
    }

}
```

Here my ejb-jar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>ItemEJB</ejb-name>
            <local-bean/>
            <ejb-class>org.abondar.experimental.javaeedemo.ejbdemo.ejb.ItemEJB</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <env-entry>
                <env-entry-name>currencyEntry</env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value>Dollars</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>
            <env-entry>
                <env-entry-name>changeRateEntry</env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type>java.lang.Float</env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value>0.90</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

Method convert price always throws NPE because both value from xml are Null. ejb-jar.xml is located src/main/resources. Is it ok? I have spent several hours and still don't understand what's going on.

Here is Aruquillian-based unit test

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class EjbTest {
    @Deployment(name = "test.jar")
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        // explicit archive name required until ARQ-77 is resolved
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")
                .addPackage(Book.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(BookEJB.class.getPackage())
                .addAsResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsManifestResource("ejb-jar.xml");


    }

 @Test
    public void convertThePriceOfAnItemTest() throws Exception {
        Item book = new Item("Cars", 10.0f, "Book of cars");
        book.setCurrency("Dollars");

        book= itemEJB.convertPrice(book);
        assertEquals("Price should be 12.5 * 0.9", Float.valueOf(11.25f), book.getPrice());
    }

}
```

Most likely unit test is misconfigured. IDEA shows that the value is seen by bean if click on it when I open the class.

Comment: "ejb-jar.xml is located src/main/resources. Is it ok?" No its not OK. It should be in `src/main/resources/META-INF/`

Comment: I changed back. There is still NPE